# BGP transitive attributes for single ASN multiple prefixes multiple neighbors

Tags: routing, bgp, internet, packet-path

I believe I'm on the right track, but have stumble across something with advertising BGP prefixes to neighbors. I am wonder how if I have a single ASN with multiple prefixes (99.1.1.0/24 and 111.1.1.0/24) with multiple upstream ISPs. How do I send BGP attributes to these upstreams to influence how ingress traffic would go to which router. See picture.
[image]

As you can see this is a GNS3 lab I put together. I have an ASN#99 with 2(two) prefixes (99.1.1.0/24 and 111.1.1.0/24). I also have two ISP neighboring routers. Tier3-1 and Tier3-2. I am trying to get from Tier1's perspective, the best path for 99.1.1.0/24 prefix is through Tier3-1 and the best paht for prefix 111.1.1.0/24 prefix is through Tier3-2.

Keep in mind, I cannot touch Tier3-1 or Tier3-2.

This is probably something simple I am missing. Appreciate everyones help.

Comment: Have you tried AS-Path prepending?  When you advertise a prefix to the ASN that you least want traffic for that prefix, prepend your AS number to the path multiple times, and don't do that for the prefix for which you do want traffic.